# if statement in html + php page

Tags: php, html

I am creating a website. The front page looks like this.

[image]

The page is created using PHP + Html + mysqli database. Anyway, what I wish to do is put an if statement, meaning that, for example, the page should only show information of customer inquiries in the database that have an annual income of more than 4500. I do not know where and in what way I should put this if statement since in HTML, the if statement is not supported. Here's the code:

```
    <?php 
    include('config/db_connect.php');

    // write query for all pizzas
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY Monthly_salary/GREATEST(Existing_loan_amount, 0.01) DESC';
    // get the result set (set of rows)

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    // fetch the resulting rows as an array
    $customers = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    // free the $result from memory (good practise)
    mysqli_free_result($result);

    // close connection
    //mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <?php include('templates/header.php'); ?>
    <h4 class="center grey-text">Enquiries!</h4>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach($customers as $customer): ?>
                <div class="col s6 m4">
                    <div class="card z-depth-0">
                        <img src="img/pizza.svg"class="pizza">
                        <div class="card-content center">
                            <h6><?php echo "Form_Submission_Time: ". htmlspecialchars($customer['Form_Submission_Time']); ?></h6>
                            <ul class="grey-text">
                                <?php foreach(explode(',', $customer['Gender']) as $Gender): ?>
                                    <li><?php echo "Gender: ". htmlspecialchars($Gender); ?></li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php foreach(explode(',', $customer['Job'])as $Job): ?>
                                    <li><?php echo "Job: ". htmlspecialchars($Job); ?></li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php foreach(explode(',', $customer['Monthly_salary']) as $Monthly_salary): ?>
                                    <li><?php echo "Annual income: ". htmlspecialchars($Monthly_salary*12); ?></li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php foreach(explode(',', $customer['Existing_loan']) as $Existing_loan): ?>
                                    <li><?php echo "Existing Loan: ". htmlspecialchars($Existing_loan); ?></li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php foreach(explode(',', $customer['Existing_loan_amount']) as $Existing_loan_amount): ?>
                                    <li><?php echo "Existing loan amount: ". htmlspecialchars($Existing_loan_amount); ?></li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php foreach(explode(',', $customer['Residential_Type']) as $Residential_Type): ?>
                                    <li><?php echo "Residential Type: ". htmlspecialchars($Residential_Type); ?></li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php foreach(explode(',', $customer['Job_Type']) as $Job_Type): ?>
                                    <li><?php echo "Job Type: ". htmlspecialchars($Job_Type); ?></li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php foreach(explode(',', $customer['MPF_account']) as $MPF_account): ?>
                                    <li><?php echo "MPF account: ". htmlspecialchars($MPF_account); ?></li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <?php 
                        $newID = ($customer['id']); 
                        ?>
                        <div class="card-action right-align"> 
                            <a class="brand-text" href="payment.php">Payment</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--<a class="brand-text" href="details.php?id=<//?php echo $customer['id'] ?>">more info</a>-->
    <?php include('templates/footer.php'); ?>
</html>
```

Comment: Either restrict on the server (Especially if you have no plans to allow the end user to see other recorde) OR you can use JavaScript if you want to toggle the display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

add a `WHERE Monthly_salary >= 4500` on the server

or use JS:

```
<li class="annual"><?php echo "Annual income: ".
```

using

```
const showIncome = amount => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".annual").forEach(li => {
    const amt = +li.textContent.trim()
    li.closest(".card").hidden = amt/12 < amount;
  })
};
```

then you can have

```
<button type="button" onclick="showIncome(4500)">4500/month or more</button>
```